# R - getting the error: "Invalid argument: 'sim' & 'obs' doesn't have the same length !"

Tags: r, rstudio, modeling, prediction, invalid-argument

I've been learning R in R Studio and have been working on simple prediction modeling.

I receive the following error:

> Invalid argument: 'sim' & 'obs' doesn't have the same length !

when I run this line of code:

```
rmse(testingbabydata$weight, predictedWeight)
```

The dataset [linked here](https://www.openintro.org/stat/data/?data=nc) contains 1000 rows and the global environment pane shows that my testing data and my training data have "500 obs. of 2 variables" each.

The library `hydroGOF` should already be loaded properly too.

This is my code snippet wherein I attempt to predict a baby's weight based on the length of the pregnancy in weeks:

```
ncbabydata=read.csv("nc.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE`)
trainingbabydata=ncbabydata[seq(1,nrow(ncbabydata),2),c("weeks","weight")]
testingbabydata=ncbabydata[seq(2,nrow(ncbabydata),2),c("weeks","weight")]
model = train(weight ~.,trainingbabydata,method="rf")
predictedWeight=predict(model,testingbabydata)
rmse(testingbabydata$weight, predictedWeight)
```

Thank you for your time! (I did attempt to google this error message first but found no suitable source that I could understand relatively easily.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two vectors are, in fact, not the same length:

```
> length(predictedWeight)
[1] 498
> length(testingbabydata$weight)
[1] 500
```

The reason for this is that some of your features are NA, and your prediction is simply omitting these rows.  Handling missing data in models is a complex topic, but since it's only two rows out of 500, you can just remove them for now and continue your learning:

```
testingbabydata<-testingbabydata[complete.cases(testingbabydata),]
```

and you can then calculate your RMSE (which you can also do directly, without a helper):

```
> sqrt(mean((testingbabydata$weight-predictedWeight)^2))
[1] 1.025823
```

and you can compare it to a model which always predicts the mean value:

```
> sqrt(mean((testingbabydata$weight-mean(testingbabydata$weight))^2))
[1] 1.460638
```